# Compiling Qt for Android, not "Qt for Android"

Tags: android, qt, cross-compiling

Let me explain the cryptic title: I am currently having a lot of trouble trying to compile Qt 5.6 in order to use it on Android. What I don't want to do is compile Qt for writing Android apps, as outlined in the Qt [wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Android) and [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html). I have no problems getting that to work, but it's not what I want. Instead, my goal is to cross compile it like I would for using it (for example) on the RasPi or Beaglebone.

This is my `.configure` command, Qt source and build directories live in `/opt/qt/`, Android NDK in `/opt/android/ndk/`:

```
./configure -device linux-arm-generic-g++ -device-option \
CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
-sysroot /opt/android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm \
-extprefix /opt/qt/android/target -hostprefix /opt/qt/android/host \
-opensource -confirm-license -opengl es2 -eglfs -no-xcb \
-skip qtwebkit -skip qtwinextras -skip qtx11extras -skip qtscript \
-skip qtactiveqt -skip qtmacextras -skip qtquick1 -v \
-I/opt/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include \
-I/opt/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include \
-L/opt/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/
```

This throws the following errors (reduced to the relevant bits):

```
error: undefined reference to 'std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)'
error: undefined reference to '__cxa_begin_catch'
error: undefined reference to '__cxa_rethrow'
error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_catch'
error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:89: recipe for target 'stl' failed
make: *** [stl] Error 1
STL disabled.
STL functionality check failed! Cannot build Qt with this STL library.
```

As you can see, `.configure` fails with undefined reference errors, which usually point to libs not linked. But which ones am I missing?

I already bumped into some errors along the way and was able to resolve them by searching through the web, but I don't know how to go from here. I am not a novice regarding cross compiling and building large code bases from projects I am not familiar with, but this has me stumped.

Did someone successfully compile Qt the way I intend to? Can someone share a configure setup or tell me if I have made an obvious error in mine?

I hope someone can and thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: what qt version you are trying to use? and what android version on board?

Comment: You want to build Qt so that you develop Qt applications on an Android platform?

Comment: What's missing is apparently related to stl. Have you tried to specify the gnu stl library to link with? (However, I'm not sure you can)